# Pyrocms: display an image in a page

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

In pyrocms admin, I have created a image field under default.I would like to pull that field in a page.

Currently my code looks like this

```
{{ if page:slug == "contact" }}
<img src="{{  template:contact_main_image:img}}"> //the field name is contact_main_image
{{ endif }}
```

but I can't see the image.

Comment: Is your code actually printing out anything in the src attribute or is your HTML displaying src="" ?  Probably need to see more of your code to know why contact_main_img isn't displaying the way you think it should.

Comment: No worries.It's fixed now.Actually the upload folder was missing so the image was not saving properly.

Comment: Please add that as the answer and mark it correct for posterity.